# How to generate Token for Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How to generate Token for Laravel Backpack?

I made the purchase of BackpackLaravel, but I only have access to the credentials, I made the tutorial that generates an auth.json file, but it still displays the purchase alert.

I think I should fill the BACKPACK_LICENSE variable with the token to solve this problem, but I can't find a way to get it.

Any light?

Comment: You can [login](https://backpackforlaravel.com/login) to your backpack account and obtain the license key from the [Licenses](https://backpackforlaravel.com/user/my-licenses) section.

Comment: when I go to the "My Licenses" section, nothing appears, but in the tokens section, it displays but with only credentials configuration (login and password) I can't generate the token.

PS: I missed informing that I use the Backpack 4.1 version but when I tried to buy it I couldn't select the version. Does that influence?

Comment: I feel this is probably better directed to the Backpack support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using Backpack v4 (which needs a license key) but you've purchased Backpack v5 (which needs the token & password have).

Email the Backpack team to convert your purchase from v5 to v4.

Comment: I did that and they sent me the token. thank you,